# Get llvm IR after lto linking

Tags: llvm, ld, lto

Is there any way to get llvm IR after linking for lto? For example I have the following line:

> $ clang -flto -O2 a.c main.c -fuse-ld=gold -v -save-temps

So I want to get llvm IR where file `a.c` and file `main.c` are linked in one `monlithic.bc` (or `monlithic.o` with IR). I tried to add option `-Wl,-plugin-opt=save-temps` but it occurs an error:

> libLLVMLTO: Unknown command line argument 'save-temps'.  Try:
>   'libLLVMLTO -help' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

And also is there any way to dump lto transformations of IR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved with newer linker and llvm (llvm-3.8 and binutils-2.25) in the following way:

> $ ls
>
> t1.c  t2.c  t2.h
>
> $ clang -flto -O2 t1.c t2.c -v -fuse-ld=gold -save-temps
>   -Wl,-plugin-opt=save-temps -Wl,--verbose
>
> ...
>
> $ ls
>
> a.out  a.out.bc  a.out.o  a.out.opt.bc  t1.bc  t1.c  t1.i  t1.o 
>   t2.bc  t2.c  t2.h  t2.i  t2.o
>
> $ llvm-dis a.out.bc
>
> $ vim a.out.ll